# How to get the sent parameters with POST (without form) on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, curl, post

I just only want to make a test and trying to understand the routes on rails. This is what I have on my *controller*:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController    
    def index
      @data = params[:number]
    end
end
```

and in *index.html.erb*

```
The number: <%= params[:number] %>
```

Well, if I made `curl http://localhost:3000/?number=100` I can see on the view:

***The number: 100***

So, here everything is correct. But, I want to do the same, but with *POST* verb. So when I made `curl -d "number=100" http://localhost:3000` I get the following error:

**No route matches [POST] "/"**

I have made:

```
def create
  render plain: params[:number].inspect
end
```

to see the parameters, but as I said before, only works with *GET* verb.

So my question: How I can see the data sent by POST to the controller with `curl` and see the result on my view *index.html.erb*?

Note: On *routes.rb* I have:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #get 'items/index'
  resources :items
  root 'items#index'
end
```

**Notes**: Based on the answer received, I have 2 more questions:

- Why the verb *GET* works on `http://localhost:3000/?number=100` and the same with `http://localhost:3000/items/?number=100`? Why the same does not happens with *POST*?
- How can I remove the message ***No route matches [POST] "/"*** if the user points directly to `http://localhost:3000` with *POST verb*?

Comment: You can add a route `POST '/' => 'items#index'` to route a post request to your index action of the items_controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting to the root_url. Instead, POST your request to the items_url:

```
curl -d "number=100" http://localhost:3000/items
```

update:

> Why the verb GET works on http://localhost:3000/?number=100 and the
>   same with http://localhost:3000/items/?number=100? Why the same does
>   not happens with POST?

The GET request to `/?number=100` works because you have specified `root 'items#index'` in your routes file. This specifically creates a `GET` route that is mapped to the `index` action of the `items` controller.

> How can I remove the message No route matches [POST] "/" if the user
>   points directly to http://localhost:3000 with POST verb?

You can create a single POST route using the `post` keyword:

```
# routes.rb
root 'items#index'
post '/', to: 'items#create'
```

which would generate the routes:

```
        root GET  /                                         items#index
             POST /                                         items#create
```

(from your project directory run the command `rails routes`)

Or you can use the `resource` method to create all the CRUD paths:

```
resources :items, path: '/'
```

... which would create the following routes:

```
       items GET    /                                         items#index
             POST   /                                         items#create
    new_item GET    /new(.:format)                            items#new
   edit_item GET    /:id/edit(.:format)                       items#edit
        item GET    /:id(.:format)                            items#show
             PATCH  /:id(.:format)                            items#update
             PUT    /:id(.:format)                            items#update
             DELETE /:id(.:format)                            items#destroy
```

Keep in mind that this may cause routing collisions if you try to add other resources to your app. If you need to add other resources, add them before these routes in the `routes.rb` file. Rails evaluates the routes file from top to bottom, so these resources would only load if no other paths match.

For more information see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Yes, now works ! But I still have some questions. I have added some notes on my original question.